# Is 板 ever read as はん when used as a suffix/prefix?

Tags: kanji, multiple-readings

I have this example sentence and I was wondering if the readings of 板 are always いた:

> 2chの野球板に書き込みをしたんですが、板違いだと言われてしまいました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a recent suffix meaning "～ board/forum", according to [this survey](http://find.razil.jp/enq/result.php/31896) and my personal experience, the majority of people read 板 as いた, but many read it as ばん, too. I probably read 野球板 as やきゅういた, but I won't say やきゅうばん is wrong.

As a standalone noun, 板 is いた. 板違い is always いたちがい. (I don't think this 板 is a prefix, although 違い might be called a suffix here).